# Adding particular List elements in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a `List[(Int,Int)]`

such that

```
{(1,5),(1,2),(1,7),(2,8),(2,3),(2,9),(3,10),(3,1),(3,12)}
```

What I want to do is to apply sum on every 2nd element of each `(1,5),(1,2),(1,7)`

2nd element of each `(2,8),(2,3),(2,9)`

and each            `(3,10),(3,1),(3,12)`

such that we have a resultant:

```
List[Int]={14, 20, 23}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might group them by the 1st element of the tuple. Then you'll have a `Map` with a key for every distinct 1st element and a `List` of all the associated 2nd elements.

```
val myMap = myList.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

Now you can `sum` the 2nd elements or apply any other transformation operation desired.

```
val mySums = myMap.mapValues(_.sum)  //Map(2 -> 20, 1 -> 14, 3 -> 23)
```

And you can extract them in some desired order.

```
mySums.keys.toList.sorted.map(mySums)  //res0: List[Int] = List(14, 20, 23)
```

Answer (score 3):

use `grouped` to split list by size, map the second value and sum, like:

```
list.grouped(3).map(_.map(_._2).sum).toList
> List(14, 20, 23)
```

Comment: thanx for consideration

Comment: @AqsaZahoor approve the answers if they answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: if i want to apply any other operation than sum i.e a function then this will not work